# Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: text/html Error with Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to create an index on a remote Elasticsearch cluster but I have this error: Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: text/html.

I know it's a known issue, but I could not find anything to help me.

Elasticsearch version: Elasticsearch 7.10
Python client Elasticsearch version: 7.10

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import gzip
import json
import os
from datetime import datetime

import boto3
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from elasticsearch import helpers
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # create ES connection with sts auth file
    es_client = Elasticsearch(
        [ES_CONFIG["es_host"]],
        port=443,
        connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
        http_auth=sts_auth(ES_CONFIG)
    )

    suffix = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d")
    resp = es_client.indices.create(index="cloudfrontlog-" + suffix, ignore=400, headers={"content-type": "application/json"})
```

Any idea of what can be wrong ?

Comment: Try to use a Python client version that is compatible with your ES server version, i.e. 7.10

Comment: Tried it and same result. Edited the question with the correct version

Answer (score 0):

Hope this issue can help other people !

Actually, the issue was that my variable ES_CONFIG["es_host"] was a value such as "myelasticsearch-cluster.amazon.com", and I had to set it with this value instead: "https://myelasticsearch-cluster.amazon.com". Now, I don't have this very misleading mimetype error anymore.